# Erlang bittorrent pieces request

Tags: erlang, block, bittorrent

I'm currently working on a BitTorrent client in Erlang. Currently I'm trying to request blocks and then build and
verify a piece from the downloaded blocks. Everything works as long as
it is not the last piece (which is of a different size than the other
pieces). It seems as if the last piece is downloaded but I can't seem
to match the hash of it against the hash retrieved from the
torrent-file. I guess I'm not really asking for a solution here, but
rather if there's something in particular that I should keep in mind
when it comes to the hash of the last piece. Is there?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. The last piece is SHA1-hashed just like the others, albeit it is smaller.

My guess is you have a bug around handling that last block and or piece correctly. One way, if glancing at the code fails, could be to test a known torrent and then compare received pieces to what you should have actually received. Start by printing out the last block when you get it and compare to the file.